# CakePHP a class that can be used anywhere?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a multi-domain site. Depending on the domain the site needs to behave accordingly.

I created a helper called `CompanyInfo` it has methods such as **name()**, **phone()**, **email()**, etc.

Depending on what domain you are on it returns the correct information.

So for example if I need to display the phone number for a user to call I would use `$this->CompanyInfo->phone()` and it will display the correct phone number for the user depending on the domain.

Ok, this is all good, but not really relevant. The real issue is, I need this information in more than just the view. Helpers are just for views though. If I want to access this information from a controller I need to create a component to do it.

I really don't want to have a Helper and a Component doing the same thing. I would rather have one class handle it rather than copy and paste logic.

So whats the best way to have a class with methods that can be accessed from the controller or view or even model?

Answer (score 1):

Is it just this kind of static information (name, phonenumber, email, etc) what you need to display? Why not just add them to your configuration in `core.php`?

Something like

```
# in core.php
Configuration::write('Company.name', 'Acme Corp.');
Configuration::write('Company.email', 'joe@acme.com');
```

You can then get this info anywhere you need using

```
Configuration::read('Company.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define this variable in your app_controller and then use these variable easily in any of your controller as set these variables from there only.
Call this function in your construct class.
i think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can access model classes from any place this way : 

    `$companyInfoModel = ClassRegistry::init('CompanyInfo');
    $phone = $companyInfoModel->phone();`

Answer (score 0):

a) you can use libs in cake1.3 for that

b) static model methods which you can pass the content to and which will return the expected value

```
echo Model::phone($data)
```